# Really strange behavior of UIButton. Crashes and gives multiple errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, uibutton

I have some serious problems with my app right now. Okay, so there are two "sign up" buttons. The upper one is "sign up" and the one below is "sign in". So if I fill out all the fields and press the "sign up" button (the upper one), then it will take me to the most right view in my storyboard image (look at the image provided) which will be called by:

```
ConfirmationScreenController *csc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Confirmation Screen"];
[self.view addSubview:csc.view];
```

and this works fine. The view shows up, but if i click the "login" button on the bottom the application crashes. The button calls this method:

```
-(IBAction)logIn:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"hello");}
```

I hooked everything up correctly I think. The strange part is : When I reset the content and settings, and run it again it will log "hello" once or twice, but when I click it once again it crashes again with `(gdb)`. Or one time it said I called the method on `__NSCFTimer`, even though I have never set up any timer or even sent anything to a timer ... What the hell is this ?

All the buttons on the MainViewController work fine.

By the way, there are no warnings when building or at runtime.

**This is the backtrace:**

```
#0  0x0183709b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00024570 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#2  0x0002455a in -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] ()
#3  0x000c9b76 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
#4  0x000ca03f in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
#5  0x000c92fe in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
#6  0x00049a30 in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
#7  0x00049c56 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#8  0x00030384 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#9  0x00023aa9 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#10 0x0157dfa9 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#11 0x016671c5 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#12 0x015cc022 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#13 0x015ca90a in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#14 0x015c9db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#15 0x015c9ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#16 0x0157c879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#17 0x0157c93e in GSEventRun ()
#18 0x00021a9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#19 0x000026f8 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff65c) at /Users/Martin/Desktop/MyApplication/MyApplication/main.m:16
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: can you add complete crash log?

Comment: What is the error message in the console when the crash occurs. What is the stack traceback? Are you using ARC?

Comment: Well, unfortunately there is nothing more than `(gdb)`...

Comment: Yes I use ARC... What is stack traceback ?

Comment: Please post the exact error text from GDB. In GDB the command "bt" will print a backtrace of the entire stack.

Comment: Add your code. The problem is that your view controller gets deallocated and a NSTimer takes its pointer (there's a default NSTimer in every application to keep the main run loop alive).

Comment: All right, posted the backtrace. What piece of code should I post ?

Comment: how do I get the code for PurpleEventCallback() ? it is not my function... How do I get the crash message ? my debugger only gives me (gdb)...

Comment: Well, `PurpleEventCallback()` looked non-Apple so I took a guess it was something you knew about.

Comment: I am having the same issue here.  I still could not find the solution.  I am using arc.  anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue, and it was because I didn't have a strong reference to the controller being created and presented - which the `IBAction` was then being called on.

Essentially, the controller is created and displayed but no one has a reference to it after that so its reference count goes to zero and it goes out of memory. So calling an action will result in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that the exception is not being caught by anyone and traveling up the stack until it cannot go further.

One way to make sure you can get a clue of where the exception is occurring is to insert a Breakpoint for ALL exceptions and on THROW  That will stop where the problem occurs and to where the exception started.

[image]

This may help in tracking down where the issue is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

***TRY THIS FIRST*** - 
In your code for presenting the confirmation screen, you simply added its view to the current viewcontroller instead of actually presenting it modally. Alter your previous code as follows:

Change

```
[self.view addSubview:csc.view];
```

to

```
[self presentModalViewController:csc animated:YES];
```

This way, the new viewcontroller will take over responding to received actions and handle them correctly. If this doesn't work, some more suggestions follow:

One thing to try is renaming the `IBAction` method, then disconnecting it in the storyboard and reconnecting it. Also, make sure the method definition in your `.h` file is *exactly* the same as the method in your `.m` file. For instance,

```
- (IBAction)logIn:(id)sender;
```

is not the same as

```
- (IBAction)logIn;
```

If you have the `(id)sender` part in one, make sure you have it in the other as well.

If none of this works, I would drop back and punt. Go to your storyboard and disconnect all your hooks and reconnect them: `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ConfirmationScreenController as the property in your header file.  I had the same issue.  But adding your subview controller as the property in your header file will prevent the crash.